# Do we use the adverbs "a lot" and "much" with countable actions, for example, "you rubbed your eyes a lot/too much"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

We often say "**you talk a lot**" or "**you talk too much**".

Do we use the adverbs "**a lot**" and "**much**" with countable actions, for example, "**you rubbed your eyes a lot/too much**" or "**you rubbed your eyes several times**"?

Comment: Yes, countable or uncountable. He kicked the dog a lot. Then it bit him.

Comment: Yes, but note that the idiom "a lot" is not an adverb but a noun phrase functioning as a degree adjunct.